# pip install not working for pandas + numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am new to Python and am trying to pip install the pandas, numpy and a few other libraries, but it won't work.

My method is:

go to command prompt and type `python -m pip install pandas --user` - I have also tried every other way like pip install etc. Each time i do it it just says syntax error. Solutions?

Thank you.

Comment: which error it's showing?

Comment: which os (windows?) and python version you're using?

Comment: Are you trying to use pip from within a python interpreter? Pip should actually be called from the command line, outside of python.

Comment: Please add your operating system info,the python interpreter and your admin privileges on your system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `pip` in python CLI. You must use `pip` in your system CLI like Windows powershell.

use command below to install packages :
`pip install pachakge-name`

for example:
`pip install numpy scipy matplotlib pandas` 
Or you can do this one by one. Each package in single line of `pip install`

Comment: thanks a heap mate ive been stuck on this for 2 days !

Comment: Your welcome. This kind of problem happens all the time. But after a short time you get how to solve. And please if your problem solved, accept the answer so the question could be closed. Good luck ;-)